# Chrome_AutocompleteEditView gone in July 2013 from Chrome Browser

Tags: google-chrome, findwindow

From 2011 to the July of 2013 i have been using FindWindowEx to get data from the Chrome Browser about current url. Today 25.09.2013 ,I've noticed that the class Chrome_AutocompleteEditView is gone... My currrent Chrome Version is 29.0.1547.76
Does anyone of you have idea how can i read this url right now ?
Below my code
Thanks

`IntPtr handle = getforegroundWindow();IntPtr urlHandle = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Chrome_AutocompleteEditView", null);`

Answer (score 0):

My problem have been solved

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Automation;
namespace ui_automation
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Description of MainForm.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("chrome"))
            {
                string url = GetChromeUrl(process);
                if (url == null)
                    continue;
                MessageBox.Show(url);
            }
        }
        public static string GetChromeUrl(Process process)
        {
            string out_url = null;
            if (process == null) {
                out_url = null;
            } else if (process.MainWindowHandle == IntPtr.Zero) {
                out_url = null;
            } else {
                AutomationElement element = AutomationElement.FromHandle(process.MainWindowHandle);
                if (element == null)
                    return null;
                Condition conditions = new AndCondition(
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ProcessIdProperty, process.Id),
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsControlElementProperty, true),
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsContentElementProperty, true),
                    new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit)
                );
                AutomationElement elementx = element.FindFirst(TreeScope.Descendants, conditions);
                out_url = ((ValuePattern)elementx.GetCurrentPattern(ValuePattern.Pattern)).Current.Value as string;
            }
            return out_url;
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not what I want exaclty.
This code works but it still getting the  URL from chrome to slow... 2 seconds or even 3 sometimes.
I noticed that, when I change TreeScope.Descendant to TreeScope.Children this code is started to run lika a flash :) but return null - nothing found.

Any ideas ?